# SQL: Dynamic Variable Names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am attempting to set variables whose names are dynamic in a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @var01 varchar(50)  
DECLARE @var02 varchar(50) 
...
DECLARE @var30 varchar(50)
DECLARE @sql = varchar(max) 

DECLARE @loopcnter INT      

-- (Inside some loop where the loopcounter increments each iteration)
...
SET @sql = 'SET @var0'+CAST(@loopcntr AS Varchar)+'= '''+'somevalue'+''''
-- e.g.) SET @var01= 'somevale'
EXEC (@sql)
```

This doesn't work because the variables are declared in a different scope to that of the dynamic sql.

What is the correct way to dynamically set variables in this manner?

Comment: why do you need the names to be dynamic? what is the larger problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Indeed, dynamic sql has its own scope

Comment: Have you tried using `@@` variables?

Comment: @@variables (global) won't work either due to the scope. The sproc reads a table using a cursor. Each colum read contains a jumbled string which is stripped of certain data, then split into substrings- comma delimited. Each set of substrings, needs to be inserted into different columns on the same row in another table. So my plan was to store each substring in its own variable, then use an insert into. (NOTE: not all inserts will have the same number of columns, so ones not used need to be inserted as NULL or '')

Comment: I don't think it's possible and I don't think it's a good idea to try to create such variable. Please give more detail what are you trying to achieve ??

Comment: Loops in SQL are evil and inefficient.  Can you show us what you're trying to accomplish in your dynamic SQL?  Maybe someone can offer an alternative.

Comment: if you want to set a value of local variable in Dynamic SQL then you should be using sp_executeSQL which has option to specify local parameters. executing dynamic sql using just EXEC(@SQL) is not a good way as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it is not pretty, but you can do:

```
if @loopcntr = 1
    set var01 = 'somevalue'
else if @loopcntr = 2
    set var02 = 'whatever'
else if . . .
```

This should be sufficiently unpleasant that you might think of alternatives.  Oh, here's a good one.  Define a table variable and just add rows in for each value:

```
declare @vars table (
    id int identity(1, 1),
    loopcntr int,
    value varchar(255)
);

. . .
-- inside the loop
    insert into @vars(loopcntr, value)
        select @loopcntr, 'whatever';
```

When you want to get a variable, you can do:

```
declare @var varchar(255);
select @var = value from @vars where loopcntr = <the one I want>;
```

Comment: +1 _"This should be sufficiently unpleasant that you might think of alternatives."_

Answer (score 0):

You can also use stored procedure sp_executesql which allows passing parameters. Although
I recommend to use additional table to store variables.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying in comments that you are assigning the set of variables merely to insert the assigned values into a table, you could use an approach avoiding the variables altogether. You could insert all the values into a temporary table or table variable, providing them with numeric indices, then pivot the column of values and insert the resulting row into the target table. So, something like this:

```
DECLARE @values TABLE (Ind int IDENTITY(1,1), Value varchar(50));

INSERT INTO @values
SELECT ...
;

INSERT INTO TargetTable (Col1, Col2, ..., Col30)
SELECT [1], [2], ..., [30]
FROM @values
PIVOT (
  MAX(Value) FOR Ind IN ([1], [2], ..., [30])
) AS p
;
```

I even suspect there might also be a possibility to do everything in such a way as to avoid the cursor you are mentioning in comments.