# Iterate through a list to get strings in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, string

I have a SQL table as shown below. I want to generate strings using the 2 fields in my table.

```
     A        B
    M1     tiger
    M1     cat
    M1     dog
    M3     lion
```

I want to read in this table, count the number of rows, and store it in string variables like String1 = M1_tiger, String2 = M1_cat, etc. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a concat type query.

```
SELECT (Table.A + '_' + Table.B) AS A_B, COUNT(*) AS RowsCount FROM Table
```

I'm asuming the your table name is "Table", the result where you will find the strings you want would be the column named A_B, each record will have two things in each record, one would be the string you asked for, the other column would always be the same thing, the total number of records on you table.

The count part is kinda easy but check this link so you can use the specific count you need: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(A, '_', B) FROM yourtable
```

Comment: You are missing, **count the number of rows**.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "read in this table", do you mean read it into a programming language like C#? Or do you want to dynamically create sql variables?

You may want to use a table variable to store your strings rather than individual variables. Regarding getting the row number, you could use something like:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
     SELECT A, B, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by OrderDate) AS 'RowNumber' 
     FROM MyTable
) 
SELECT A,B,RowNumber FROM CTE
```

See this answer for more on how you may choose to use the table variable.
[SQL: Dynamic Variable Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772661/sql-dynamic-variable-names)

Comment: The table is already there; I just want to create strings from that table. By 'read in' I mean use the query to select it

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that if you want to create dynamic variables to put the strings produced from your query in, I don't think you can do that. But you could create a query that creates the strings as you want to use them and store then in a table variable (not a true table). Then you could reference the rows inside the table variable to access these newly created strings.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using Oracle, you can  also do it like:

select A ||'_'||B 
 from yourTable

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for PostgreSQL**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE one; 
SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(concat('String',nextval('one'),' = ',A,'_',B)), ', ')
AS result
FROM test_table; 
DROP SEQUENCE one;
```

**Explanation:**

- **Create** a temporary sequence 'one' in order to use `nextval` function.
- **nextval**('sequence') - advance sequence and return new value.
- **concat**('input1', ...) - concatenate all arguments.
- **array_agg**('input1', ...); - input values, including nulls,
  concatenated into an array.
- **array_to_string**('array', 'delimiter') - concatenates array elements
  using supplied delimiter and optional null string.
- **Drop** the sequence 'one'.

**The output** of the query (for two test rows in test_table):

```
                  result                   
-------------------------------------------
 String1 = M1_tiger, String2 = M1_cat
(1 row)
```