# In a SQL Server stored procedure, can a loop be used to access the values of multiple-parameters if the paramaters are named similarly?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, parameters, dynamic-sql

I have a stored procedure which is supposed to query based on user selections. The stored procedure takes three GUID parameters (user selected) and holds each GUID in it's own variable called '@GUID_X' where X would be an integer in the range of [1-15).

The stored procedure needs to query for these GUID values and since there is a pattern to the variable names, I'd like to use a loop to iterate through the variables to access their values and then insert each value into the query.

So far, I've tried concatenating '@GUID_' + 'counter number' and ended up with a list of values such as:

```
@FoodGUID_3
@FoodGUID_2
@FoodGUID_1
```

When in reality, I was expecting a list that looked like:

```
ABABABA1-FGH-1234-ZX12-123456EDVERT
GHDF1234-CVB-4312-CV15-678912NK1284
VBNM5678-BVC-2134-BN18-852741DC1434
```

Why can't I access the actual GUID values of the declared `@FoodGUID_X` args? What would be a better way of approaching this problem? Ideally the approach wouldn't be to use an 'if' clause for each arg since this might be expensive!

For ref. here if my full code:

```
DECLARE @foodGUID_1 NVARCHAR(360) = N'ABABABA1-FGH-1234-ZX12-123456EDVERT',
        @foodGUID_2 NVARCHAR(360) = N'GHDF1234-CVB-4312-CV15-678912NKOMLP',
        @foodGUID_3 NVARCHAR(360) = N'VBNM5678-BVC-2134-BN18-852741DCFVGB'

DECLARE @SelectSQL NVARCHAR(2500) = 'Query string  + '
DECLARE @NumOfFoodsSelected INT = 3
DECLARE @counter INT = @NumOfFoodsSelected
DECLARE @currentGUID NVARCHAR(360)

SET @currentGUID  = '@DeviceGUID_'+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(15), @counter)

PRINT @currentGUID

WHILE (@counter != 1)
BEGIN
    SET @counter = @counter - 1
    SET @currentGUID  = '@DeviceGUID_'+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(15), @counter)
    PRINT @currentGUID
END
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help! :)

Comment: are you trying to achieve something like dynamic variables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: Dynamic Variable Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772661/sql-dynamic-variable-names)

Comment: You can create another stored procedure and call it repeatedly with the 3 variables.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [UDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) as parameter on your stored procedure to store your GUIDs.

So your script will look like this.

```
declare @goodGuids table (
    id int identity(1, 1), 
    foodguid NVARCHAR(360)
);

insert into @goodGuids(foodguid) values
        (N'ABABABA1-FGH-1234-ZX12-123456EDVERT'),
        (N'GHDF1234-CVB-4312-CV15-678912NKOMLP'),
        (N'VBNM5678-BVC-2134-BN18-852741DCFVGB')

select 'DeviceGUID_' + foodguid from @goodGuids
```

Answer (score 0):

A [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) can be used to access the names and values:

```
DECLARE     @foodGUID_1 NVARCHAR(360) = N'ABABABA1-FGH-1234-ZX12-123456EDVERT',
            @foodGUID_2 NVARCHAR(360) = N'GHDF1234-CVB-4312-CV15-678912NKOMLP',
            @foodGUID_3 NVARCHAR(360) = N'VBNM5678-BVC-2134-BN18-852741DCFVGB';

select VariableValue
  from ( values
    ( '@foodGUID_1', @foodGUID_1 ),
    ( '@foodGUID_2', @foodGUID_2 ),
    ( '@foodGUID_3', @foodGUID_3 )
    ) as foodGUIDs( VariableName, VariableValue )
  where VariableName = '@foodGUID_2';
```

The `where` clause could be `where VariableName = '@foodGUID_' + Cast( @Counter as VarChar(2) )` for brute force looping through the values. The value can be retrieved in a variable using `select @foodGUID = VariableValue from ...`

The table value constructor can be used in a variety of queries as a *derived table*, e.g. to `insert` multiple rows into a table or as one side of a `join` in a `select`.